# Visual Studio 2010 Designer Error on Run

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, designer

I am using using VS2010 and if I have a form open in designer mode and run my application the designer tab will no longer show the form designer  but instead an error will be displayed (and it is only fixed by restarting the IDE) saying:

> "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the
>   following errors must be resolved:"
>
> 1 Error:
>
> "The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the
>   classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the
>   following classes in the file: ##### --- The base class ##### could
>   not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all
>   projects have been built"

I then shows the following call stack:

> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
>   at          Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)

Any help is greatly appreciated this is really annoying.

Thanks,

Joel.

Answer (score 36):

I get this visual studio bug too now and then, and I deeply ignore the error text, instead I do the following:

1. Close the Design-tab
2. Reopens the Design mode by double click in Solution Explorer, or by right clicking Source code tab and select View Designer
3. Suddenly everything works again!

If not helping, you may have to change bullet 2 into:
Close and restart Visual Studio.

Maybe this can help you out.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but I would like to not have to restart the IDE every time this happens (which is a lot of times).

Comment: I agree, but until Bill Gates fixes the bug I guess you (and I) have to.

Comment: I too am hitting this problem often and unfortunately, I end up needing to restart VS.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. What kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: I have same issue on VS 13. And this didn't worked. :(

Comment: restarting visual studio didnt work because it now saves the open tabs so `right click any document tab > close all documents`. now try.

Answer (score 7):

I usually close the visual form, rebuild the solution, right-click then select "view designer" in the form code.

Very, very annoying. I am thinking of dropping back to VS2008.

Comment: worked for me, but I did a clean solution first. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Close the form. Clean the solution. Rebuild the solution. Reopen the form. Worked for me when nothing else would.

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to avoid restarting VS by doing the following

1. Add a new user control
2. Drag and drop some of your custom user controls on to it (If it gives you an error, build the solution again).
3. Reopen your control.

In my case, I have a winforms project with several custom controls that are used by other custom controls. Whenever I open some of those custom controls, I get a the "The base class ..." error. Adding a new custom control, building the project and then adding some custom controls from my project to the new custom control allowed me to open the custom controls that were giving me the "The base class ..." error.

UPDATE: I think I found the problem. My controls were not 'added' properly to the csproj file. In the csproj file, the files for partial classes of UI controls/components need the 'DependentUpon' attribute.

E.x.:
before:

```
<Compile Include="Windows\Forms\DataGridView.cs">
    <SubType>Component</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Windows\Forms\DataGridView.Designer.cs" />
```

after:

```
<Compile Include="Windows\Forms\DataGridView.cs">
    <SubType>Component</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Windows\Forms\DataGridView.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>DataGridView.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: +1 to this - I noticed that mine had "corrupted" itself and any custom controls threw this error. I had a backup of my vbproj file and compared the two and fixed the errors.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and I was able to resolve this by creating new project and then compiled and run the project and then I imported all the files and ran the project again and automatically it was working again did nothing extra.

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation where a custom user control appeared to be creating the error (not sure why) so I removed references to the user control from the form and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after installing SP1 the problem has gone away.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using A control With Generics

```
      MvpUserControl<Presenter,IViewMode> : UserControl
```

what I do it's Remove the Reference and Add again, Clean and Rebuild the Solution I Hope this can be useful for anybody else

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VS2010 SP1. Finally using Windows Update I saw some updates for Visual Studio and .Net, I installed them and is not happening any more.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but for those whom may find this...

Just ran in to this error and for me it was relatively simple fix.

Found that it may have something to do with the names of your classes, and renaming the problematic class to a higher order. That is the alphabetical order it appears in the assembly (Where A is higher than Z).

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CodeDomDesignerLoaderNoRootSerializer%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur if the Form class is not a first class in the file, for example if there is some helper class at the beginning of the file.

To solve this issue, move all other classes except Form class to the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't code in **Form1.Designer.cs**. Move your logic to **Form1.cs** (hit F7 on **Form1.cs [Design]** tab).

Answer (score 0):

> "In the project file (.vcxproj), locate the entry for the target
> Framework version. For example, if your project is designed to use the
> .NET Framework 4.5, locate
> v4.5 in the
>  element of the  element. "
>
> (Microsoft)

In my case the "v4.5" didn't exist so I add it, and everything is good now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried clean solution and re-build solution and worked for me.
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine, please follow these steps below to solve your problem:

1. Check the reference if load correctly
2. Clean the solution and rebuild again
3. Clean the project and rebuild again
4. Clean your project and open it again

Answer (score 0):

I was login as administrator in visual studio . I just close my visual studio and again open it without run as administrator and my problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today after upgrading VS2019.  I went to properties, configuration tab, and set the projects to Configuration = **Debug**, Platform = **Any CPU**.  Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue.

> To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

I found solution for this problem:

Close all open tabs, and refresh (sync active documents) the solution.

[image]

For more information, you can see this video : https://youtu.be/Q3x2HBd7BDs